# Is there a way to get an explicit warning message from Chrome, not just a yellow triangle?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

When I view the following HTML5

```css
.box {
    width: 250px; height: 150px;
    background-color: #ddd;
    margin: 5px;
}
.vcent {
    vertical-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <img class="vcent" src="icon.svg" />
</div>

<div class="box">
    <a href="index.html"><img class="vcent" src="icon.svg" /></a>
</div>
```

using Chrome (78.0), and with the following `icon.svg`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    width="30pt" height="15pt" viewBox="0 0 300 150" version="1.1">
    <g id="surface1">
        <rect x="20" y="20" rx="10" ry="10" width="260" height="110" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

I get a yellow-triangle warning

[image: yellow triangle warning from Chrome]

signaling that Chrome rejected the styling.

In this case Chrome is unhappy because I used `center` rather than `middle`.

Is there any way to determine *why* Chrome rejected the styling? Can I get an explicit warning message "`center` is not allowed for this style", for example? (Does any other HTML5 IDE provide more helpful messages?)

I'm at this moment trying to increase my autonomy, and so I'm, metaphorically, trying to learn how to fish on my own. If you see the issue and can provide a fish in the form of how to get the icon centered—in the presence or the absence of an `a` tag—please do. I'm sure after [wrestling](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp) with the centering issue (for this nth time) I'll figure it out.

Comment: You can use a linter in your IDE such as https://stylelint.io

Comment: *Can I get an explicit warning* --> for me what you get is more than explicit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Just hover your mouse over the icon.

Comment: Very interesting. I had been clicking the triangle, and apparently too quickly. The hover text is under a delay. Could you also comment why the triangle disappears when one clicks on it? Is one then in some other special mode?